# mapping and returning _.uniq values without duplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a little mapping going on... in my example I have tried to return duplicate values only once by adding `<h3 key={i}>{_.uniq(person.name)}</h3>` lodash's shortcut. As you can see from the outputs its returning the duplicate vales from its object array.

```
{Object.keys(result).map((item, index) =>
    <div key={index} className="report">
        <div className="contact-item">
            {result[item].map((person, i) =>
                <h3 key={i}>{_.uniq(person.name)}</h3> 
               //OUTPUT "tom"
               //OUTPUT "GregGreg"
               //OUTPUT "Phil"
               //OUTPUT "timtim"
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
)}

result = 
0: {Number: 1, newNumber:"1", name: "tom" }
1: [{Number: 2, newNumber: "2", name: "Greg" }, {Number: 2, newNumber: "4", name: "Greg" }]
2: {Number: 3, newNumber: "3", name: "Phil" }
3: [{Number: 4, newNumber: "4", name: "tim" }, {Number: 2, newNumber: "3", name: "tim" }]
```

I only want to return "tim" and "Greg" once as its a duplicate, therefore not unique. the _.uniq declaration is not doing anything. I have tried other lodash declarations such as union etc... and uniqBy. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `_.unique` expects an array but you are passing it a string value. Can you share a sample structure for `result`? But as of now, you can try `_.unique(result[item]).map(...)`

Comment: Yes I tried _.uniq(result[item]) previously but still returns the two values.

Comment: Then we would need more information. Like sample data

Comment: result output is as it comes out of the console, detailed in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the desired result, all I needed to do was to `.slice(0, 1)` to bring one item back.

```
{Object.keys(result).map((item, index) =>
    <div key={index} className="report">
        <div className="contact-item">
            {result[item].map((person, i) =>
                <h3 key={i}>{_.uniq(person.name)}</h3> 
               //OUTPUT "tom"
               //OUTPUT "GregGreg"
               //OUTPUT "Phil"
               //OUTPUT "timtim"
            ).slice(0, 1)}
        </div>
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source data looks the same as your result data you could do the following:

```
_.chain(people).flatten().uniqBy('name').value()
```

This lodash statement will flatten the array and then return distinct values based on the name field. I've used lodash's chain function to make the code more succinct.

An example of this working can be seen in this example:

https://repl.it/@8enSmith/ExemplarySereneToolbox

Answer (score 0):

With lodash there are more than one way to get what you are looking for. Here are few examples:

```js
var people = [
[{Number: 1, newNumber:"1", name: "tom" }],
[{Number: 2, newNumber: "2", name: "Greg" }, {Number: 2, newNumber: "4", name: "Greg" }],
[{Number: 3, newNumber: "3", name: "Phil" }],
[{Number: 4, newNumber: "4", name: "tim" }, {Number: 2, newNumber: "3", name: "tim" }]
]

console.log(_.chain(people).flatten().uniqBy('name').value())
console.log(_.chain(people).flatten().sortedUniqBy('name').value())

// this would pivot and keep the arrays as children
console.log(_.chain(people).flatten().groupBy('name').value()) 

// With loadsh/fp you could flow it
// console.log(_.flow(_.flatten, _.uniqBy('name'))(people))
// console.log(_.flow(_.flatten, _.sortedUniqBy('name'))(people))
// console.log(_.flow(_.flatten, _.groupBy('name'))(people))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```